# Aspects not Working within @SpringBoot class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I am trying to integrate AspectJ and SpringBoot. It was running fine until I tried experimenting a bit and used:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestClassRunner {

    @MyAnnotation
    public void someDisplay(){
         System.out.println("My Display");
    }

    @Bean(name="dummyString")
    public String getString(){
         someDisplay();
         return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

The Aspect class is defined as:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAnnotationProcessor{

    @Before("@annotation(myTest.MyAnnotation)")
    public void aroundSampleCreation(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
         System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature());
         System.out.println("Executing the Before call");
   }
}
```

Now this Advice is not getting executed. Is it because of some special character of the @Configuration class (I know @SpringBoot uses that internally)?

I have included all the dependencies and that should not be the cause of this not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: make this `"@annotation(myTest.MyAnnotation)"` `"@annotation(MyAnnotation)"`

Comment: It is an internal method call, internal method calls don't pass through the proxy created by Spring to apply AOP hence no execution of your aspect.

Comment: I am a newbie so not sure but I think as of this point, for using the @Before, we are not creating a Proxy object for the MainClass. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: When you use Aspect, proxy is created internally. The easiest way to fix this is put your method `someDisplay` in  a separate spring bean. And call it using an instance of that bean from `getString`

Comment: Yup that is correct. I used **new TestClassRunner().someDisplay();** and it worked. Since I am using AspectJ are proxy created for all my beans generated?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of AspectJ it is the way Spring, by default, implements AOP through proxies.